# Is there any way to convert/compare JasperReports's report 'band height' to/with inches?

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports, ireport

I am making labels using *iReport* and need to make sure they fit with the labels the client uses. I am using label format Avery 5163 which has a height of 2 inches. The labels I'm making need to match up with the labels they will be using to print.

I can only find a 'band height' property in *iReport* which is definitely not in inches. I could fiddle with the band height until they lined up with the Avery 5163 label heights, but I don't like wasting paper and I have more of these labels with different sizes I'd love to know a way to handle this. Has anyone experienced this or know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the dimensions of Jasper Reports labels are defined in "dots", with 72 dots per inch.

So your 2 inch label would require a height of 144 units.